# How to hide ListFragment?

Tags: android

Is there any way to hide ListFragment? I would like to make it invisible after starting the ListFragment application, only after pressing the 'Ranking' button it becomes visible.

I tried to set visibility invisible in options in the layout, but unfortunately it doesn't do anything. ListView is displayed all the time after starting the application.

Answer (score 1):

At first, add some code for example how you tried to do this.
If you want to hide ListFragment - set visibility gone to it's container.
If you want to hide ListView - set visibility gone to it.